# How to correct Hindi text rendering when using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a FFmpeg script to add some Hindi text to the MP4 video file.

The FFmpeg command looks like this

```
ffmpeg -i template_video.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=text='नमस्कार जी मैं हूँ':fontfile=mukta.ttf:fontsize=40:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=530:y=530:enable='between(t,20,22)'[output]; [output] drawtext=text='आज हम स्कैन करेंगे':fontfile=mukta.ttf:fontsize=20:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=100:y=100:enable='between(t,15,20)'[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a? -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1080x1920 output_video.mp4 -y
```

Expected:

[image]

Actual:

[image: Image of hindi text rendered on video using ffmpeg]

[image: Image of hindi text rendered on video using ffmpeg]

As you can see the Hindi half letters are not getting rendered.

Half Letter

[image: Half hindi letter 'sa']

Full letter

[image: Full hindi letter 'sa']

Also, If I change the font then it is rendering the text like these boxes.

*I have used two fonts the upper one is Mukta the bottom one is Tahoma*

[image]

I have gone through and tried these links:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008770/cant-render-or-join-hindi-ligatures-in-ffmpeg-drawtext/49307338#49307338) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298061/ffmpeg-drawtext-support-for-hindi-fonts).

I also tried this [GitHub](https://github.com/abusaadp/Unity3dHindiRenderer) link.

Am I missing something to make it render properly?

Comment: “As you can see the Hindi half letters are not getting rendered.” Confused. I don’t know Hindi, but it seems to me the main difference between the two images is text being rendered on different lines? I am not too sure what “Hindi half letters” means. Can you perhaps explain more?

Comment: Hey @Giacomo1968 you are right. I have added the letter for explanation.

Comment: And what was the result of you trying these? It's not clear. Also, don't crosspost please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78069908/correct-hindi-text-drawing-when-using-ffmpeg